# Chain rule in the context of backpropagation in Recurrent Neural Networks - Understanding a derivation

Tags: chain-rule

I am studying on my own about RNNs and particularly backpropagation.  I have found in the web a slide presentation explaining backpropagation step by step but I am stuck in a particular slide I can not understand.  Could you help me understand the derivation?  I provide below the two adjacent slides of the presentation that are relevant:

[image]

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated!  Thank you!